# Adding a parameter before the page name in SilverStripe 3.x

Tags: routes, silverstripe

I have been searching the web for a few hours but can't find anything that answers my query.

If I have pages in my site tree of:

- Home

  - Page 1
  - Page 2

I would then access these pages by visiting:

- www.mysite.com
- www.mysite.com/page1
- www.mysite.com/page2

How can I set up routes so that I can access the pages as follows?

- www.mysite.com/client1
- www.mysite.com/client1/page1
- www.mysite.com/client1/page2
- www.mysite.com/client2
- www.mysite.com/client2/page1
- www.mysite.com/client2/page2

Whereby client1, client2 etc is a variable value that will be used to identify a client for branding etc.

Comment: Having the client as the `$URLSegment` part of the route is probably possible, but it will disable the possibility to have any "regular" page next to it… eg. `www.mysite.com/contact` is then not going to work. Would it also work to switch the URL structure? Eg. `www.mysite.com/page1/client1`?

Comment: All content on the site will be specific to the client so there will never be a situation where there won't be a client in the URL. I have looked at Routing in Silverstripe but I can't seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Incase anyone else is struggling with this, after much googling, I finally figured this out.

I needed to add this to my config.yml

```
---
Name: modelascontrollerroutes
After: cms/routes#modelascontrollerroutes
---
Director:
  rules:
    '': 'RootURLController'
    '$Client': 'RootURLController'
    '$Client/$URLSegment//$Action/$ID/$OtherID': 'ModelAsController'
```

Answer (score 3):

You could either use one of those modules

- [Subsites](https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-subsites)
- [Multisites](https://github.com/silverstripe-australia/silverstripe-multisites)

or create something like a "ClientLanding" pagetype, where you could select a theme, make client specific settings, eg.